# How does the adjustment of the amplitude work (in Audio)

Tags: frequency

I'm trying to understand how the adjustment of amplitude of audio works.

More specifically: Does changing the amplitude of a Sine Wave only work one cycle at a time.

To make things simple I'm thinking of changing the amplitude of a simple sine wave over time. I understand that raising the amplitude is achieved by simply "layering" more of that same wave.

But what happens when you adjust the amplitude in less time then the wave takes to complete one cycle. Does that change the shape of the wave in a way that leads to other frequencies showing up?

Let's say Im playing a Sine Wave at 50hz does changing the amplitude of this sound only work every 20 milli seconds without changing the wave?

Hope I was able to make the question clear enough.

Thanks!

Comment: a resistive voltage divider changes the instantaneous (input) voltage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle you can change the amplitude of a sine or cosine wave as fast as you want. Imagine playing a single note on a digital piano, giving a sound signal $s(t)=cos(\omega t)$ Now you start sliding the volume control up and down as a function of time. If the volume is given by $A(t)$ the sound $s(t)$ will behave as $$s(t)=A(t)cos(\omega t).$$ Mathematically there is no problem with changing the volume in a shorter time than the period of the sine wave, although your digital piano might not keep up.

However, as you already noticed yourself, if you alter the amplitude very fast, the output signal will stop looking like a cosine wave. And indeed the output signal will no longer be a signal with a single frequency, but a combination of many frequencies.

What you might not have realized is that this also occurs for slow variations of the amplitude. Imagine we vary the amplitude slowly in a cosine-like fashion: $A(t)=cos(\omega_{slow} t)$. You might know the trigonometric relation $$cos(a) \cdot cos(b)= cos(a+b) + cos(a-b).$$ This leads to 
$$s(t)=A(t)cos(\omega_{note}t)=cos(\omega_{slow}t)cos(\omega_{note}t)$$ 
$$=cos(\omega_{slow}+\omega_{note}) + cos(\omega_{slow}-\omega_{note}).$$

What this tells us is that even if we change the amplitude very slowly, the final signal will no longer be a single cosine with the original frequency, but it will be a sum of different frequency components.

The only signals that have a single frequency therefore are sines and cosines with a constant amplitude.